# Parameters Query in Teradata- Am getting Failed this error message [3639 : 22018] Comparing BYTE data with other types is illegal

Tags: sql, teradata

am new to Teradata and I have been having trouble using parameter query in my code. Below is my code

```
SELECT SQS_DATE_LKP.SQS_DATE,
SQS_DATE_LKP.DATE_FMT,
SQS_DATE_LKP.WEEKDAY_NO,
SQS_DATE_LKP.WEEKDAY_NAME,
SUBSTR (SQS_DATE_LKP.FISC_WEEK,7,2) AS FISCAL_WEEK,
SQS_DATE_LKP.FISC_PERIOD
FROM SPE_SEM_VW.SQS_DATE_LKP
WHERE FISCAL_WEEK=?
;
```

First I used substring on my FISC_WEEK column because the initial column is in the format (2021-W34) and am only interested in value (34) so I used the substring to get rid of everything that comes before 34. Next, I used (?) as a way to pass in my parameter but when I execute the query it gives me this error 'Executed as Single statement.  Failed [3639 : 22018] Comparing BYTE data with other types is illegal'

I tried to run the query before without using the substring and it worked perfectly, however that is not what am looking for since the absence of the substring will require me to input '2021-W34' in the pop up table that comes when you run the query. My goal is that when I run the query and the parameter pop up table comes up, I want to be able to just put the value 34 and have all records corresponding to week 34. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Applying SUBSTR to a character field gives a VARCHAR so apparently whatever client client software is prompting you for a value is telling the database the value `34` is a BYTE data type (or maybe not setting a type. It may work if you enter `'34'` with the quotes. You could CAST the SUBSTR as an INTEGER or SMALLINT type for a numeric comparison, but that won't help if the incoming parameter is still set to BYTE.

Comment: @Fred I tried 34 with the quotes but it's not helping either. I guess I will have to use the original column name without using SUBSTR